# Swift enum opaque return type

Tags: arrays, swift, enums, opaque-result-type

I've been experimenting with this [code example](https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/handling-model-variants-in-swift/) from John Sundell and want to be able to get an enum value from the array.

```
protocol ItemVariant: Decodable {
    var title: String { get }
    var imageURL: URL { get }
}

struct Video: ItemVariant {
    var title: String
    var imageURL: URL
    var url: URL
    var duration: String
    var resolution: String
}

struct Recipe: ItemVariant {
    var title: String
    var imageURL: URL
    var text: String
    var ingredients: [String]
}

enum Item {
    case video(Video)
    case recipe(Recipe)
}


extension Item: Decodable {
    struct InvalidTypeError: Error {
        var type: String
    }

    private enum CodingKeys: CodingKey {
        case type
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let type = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .type)

        switch type {
        case "video":
            self = .video(try Video(from: decoder))
        case "recipe":
            self = .recipe(try Recipe(from: decoder))
        default:
            throw InvalidTypeError(type: type)
        }
    }
}

struct ItemCollection: Decodable {
    var items: [Item]
}

let json = """
{
    "items": [
        {
            "type": "video",
            "title": "Making perfect toast",
            "imageURL": "https://image-cdn.com/toast.png",
            "url": "https://videoservice.com/toast.mp4",
            "duration": "00:12:09",
            "resolution": "720p"
        },
        {
            "type": "recipe",
            "title": "Tasty burritos",
            "imageURL": "https://image-cdn.com/burritos.png",
            "text": "Here's how to make the best burritos...",
            "ingredients": [
                "Tortillas",
                "Salsa",
            ]
        }
    ]
}
"""

let result = try JSONDecoder().decode(ItemCollection.self, from: json.data(using: .utf8)!)
print(result.items)
```

I want to add the following:

```
extension Item {
    var value: some ItemVariant {
        switch self {
        case .recipe(let recipe):
            return recipe
        case .video(let video):
            return video
        }
    }
}
```

Allow for something like this:

```
print(result.items.first { $0.value is Video })
```

But I end up with this compiler error:
`function declares an opaque return type, but the return statements in its body do not have matching underlying types`

I'm not sure how I can resolve this error and find an elegant way to retrieve a enum value from an enum array.  Appreciate any help.

Comment: I think you mean `any ItemVariant`, not `some ItemVariant`. Did you try that?

Comment: Agggghh, I had been looking at this code for hours.  Thank you VERY much @Sweeper that did the trick.

Are you able to explain why `some` wouldn't work?

Comment: To answer your question, a function that returns an _Opaque_ value (aka `some T`) must return a value of _one_ and _only one_ concrete type conforming to `T`. That is, the returned value is always the same concrete type and consequently it must be known at compile time. 
A function that returns `any T` returns some kind of a "box" (aka _existential_) conforming to `T` whose content is a value that conforms to `T` but otherwise can be _any concrete_ and conforming type. The concrete type can be determined at runtime, depending on the implementation.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper in the case of a `Video` and `Recipe` concrete types, even though they conform to `ItemVariant` they are associated types of the `enum Item` and the reason why  `some` didn't work.  So with `var value: any ItemVariant` there doesn't appear a way I can get the concrete type from the array, only the common properties of `ItemVariant`.  

Set enum as `indirect enum Item`, that then cast to the type I want.  For example:
`if let value = result.items.first(where: { $0.value is Recipe }) { print((value.value as! Recipe).ingredients) }`


Is that your understanding?

Comment: Exactly, `var value: any ItemVariant` is valid, but doesn't return the concrete type, only the "existential" which conforms (only) to the `ItemVariant` protocol. In scenarios like this, you may use a `switch` statement in order to extract the concrete underlying associated type. After all your decoder returns an Enum. Alternatively, add helper accessors to the enum like `var recipe: Recipe?` and `var video: Video?`. Note, that the helper accessors return an optional. This technique is quite common. ;)

Comment: @CouchDeveloper thanks for helping me out.  So there is no way I can get the `var value: any ItemVariant` to return the concrete type of `Recipe` or `Video` and the only way is as you've suggested is to add the helper accessors for each enum value which seems to duplicate the effort. i.e `var video: Video? { switch self { case .video(let value): return value default: return nil } }`

Comment: John Sundell shows another interesting way to extract the desired value: `@dynamicMemberLookup` with a subscript and a `KeyPath`. But keep in mind, when you have an Enum, which contains _either_ a value of type `A` _or_ a value of type `B`, there's no way to know upfront what it contains until you try.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper just a followup to this question.  Ultimately I need to be able to display the enum i.e `result.items` values in SwiftUI.

Something like:
```